# Sum function not working in Java.

Tags: java

I'm new to Java programming.  I have a project that is supposed to sum a series of inputs and also calculate the average of those numbers.  Right now the Total is coming up as zero no matter what I put in for values.  I'm stuck.  Please help.  Thank you.

```
   private class InputButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {  
                 for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
                 {
                       numInput = 0.0;
                       strInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many hours did you sleep on day " + (i+1));
                       numInput = Double.parseDouble(strInput);
                       numInput +=total;                        
                 }
          }
   }
   private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The total amount of sleep for the week is " + total + " hours");

                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The average amount of sleep for 7 days is " + avg + " hours");
          }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
          {
                 HoursSlept HS = new HoursSlept();
          }
```

}

Comment: I don't know where `total` is defined, but I'm almost positive that you have the last line of the for loop backwards. You probably want `total += numInput`. That's probably your issue.

Comment: `numInput +=total;` You are adding the value of `total` to `numInput`.  Did you mean to do the opposite: `total += numInput;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to be here

```
numInput +=total;
```

It should be

```
total += numInput;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `total += numInput` instead of `numInput += total`.

```
for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
{
    strInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many hours did you sleep on day " + (i+1));
    numInput = Double.parseDouble(strInput);
    total += numInput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The += operator works the other way around.

Your issue is here:

```
numInput += total;
```

Should be

```
total += numInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you supposed to switch total and numInput?

```
for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
             {
                   numInput = 0.0;
                   strInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many hours did you sleep on day " + (i+1));
                   numInput = Double.parseDouble(strInput);
                   total +=numInput;                        
             }
```